# Problems learning FontConverter

Tags: vb.net

My trying code:

```
Dim Flag as String, P_Font as Font
Flag = "Comic Sans MS, 15.75pt"
Debug.Print(Flag)
Dim cvt As New FontConverter
P_Font = CType(cvt.ConvertFromString(Flag), Font)
Debug.Print(P_Font.ToString)
Flag = cvt.ConvertToInvariantString(P_Font)
Debug.Print(Flag)
```

The Debug.Print output:

```
Comic Sans MS, 15.75pt
[Font: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif, Size=8,25, Units=3, GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]
Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt
```

Why FontConverter changes Font Family and Size??

**EDIT:**

Changed:

P_Font = CType(cvt.ConvertFromString(Flag), Font)

to

P_Font = CType(cvt.ConvertFrom**Invariant**String(Flag), Font)

now the code works.

Comment: That code assumes that `"Comic Sans MS, 15.75pt"` is a complete and valid `InvariantString` for that font, but it is not.  Since it cannot convert, default values are used.

Comment: Works just fine on my machine.  Seems your machine doesn't have the font, odd.

Comment: Ty for the answers... my PC has the font, I have edited my question thanks to the answer of Plutonix